# How to interrupt a Vim command taking too much time?

Tags: vim

Sometimes a Vim command takes too much time to execute.

Typical example : `gf` command with a huge path over a network. It can take up to 30 seconds to end. I would like to interrupt the execution while it is ongoing.

Is there a way to cancel the command execution and go back to normal mode (without having to kill Vim and restart) ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can interrupt it sending SIGINT (CTRL+C).

Comment: I thought I had already tried because it would seem the most natural thing to try but apparently I had not be paying enough attention.

Comment: I thought it will cancel the whole application (vim), but it just stopped the ongoing operation. Thanks!

Comment: @nuoritoveri if Ctrl-C stopped the vim process there would be far fewer jokes and memes about not being able to exit vim :)

Comment: `Ctrl+C` doesn't work for `vimgrep`, e.g. searching a pattern through very large set of files

Comment: Not working for `coc.nvim`.

Answer (score 7):

From [the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#CTRL-C):

```
CTRL-C      Interrupt current (search) command.  Use CTRL-Break on
            MS-DOS |dos-CTRL-Break|.
            In Normal mode, any pending command is aborted.
```