# A Stop button in VIM

Tags: vim, process

Often I test a function or click too often on an key on my keyboard.
I can't stop the output of the function... I can't stop VIM doing what it is asked to do.

Is there a way to Stop all processes in VIM?

Comment: are these 'long' processes vim functions or child processes executed by vim?

Comment: @IanNorton, mostly vim functions, sometimes vim commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5005970/513198) recently.

`CTRL+C` works most of the time to interrupt a long process.

To add a button, see `:help toolbar-icon`.
It should be something like `:amenu icon=[icon-path] Toolbar.Stop <C-C>`

Comment: so simple? :) But how can I put this in a button (icon) on the toolbar (and be sure that it doesn't interfere with the copy command)?

Comment: @Remonn : CTRL+C is only redefined as copy in mswin.vim I guess, the standard copy command is `p`. I have had a quick look at mswin.vim, apparently `C-C` is only redefined in Visual mode. So in normal mode, using CTRL+C should work. See :help toolbar-icon to add a button.

Comment: Obviously the standard copy command is 'y' but I can't edit my previous comment :).

Comment: yes `C_C` is defined as copy in mswin.vim, mswin.vim is sourced by default in the _vimrc version of gvim. I still use  `C-C`, `C-V`, `C-Z` in VIM (also `y`, `p`, `u`)

Comment: To get fully rid of the Windows-type copy and paste mappings you can remove the line `behave mswin` that is near the top of your vimrc file.  I do have the Windows mappings enabled in my Windows install and ctrl-c does still generally work to stop a script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ctrl-break on Windows. I do not think it would work well as a button since if Vim is kicking out a lot of output it may not be able to service the GUI functionality fast enough.

On Windows (with mswin.vim)  ctrl-break, everywhere else ctrl-c.